# Trying to fix app javascript type error for app development

Tags: javascript, fitbit

Trying to switch between screens on a FitBit app that uses .js. I can switch to the second screen in the first onclick but the second one will not work. How can I fix this?

```
import document from "document";

let myRect = document.getElementById("gen_button");
let tumbler = document.getElementById("tumbler");
let back = document.getElementById("ok");

myRect.onclick = function(e) {
  document.replaceSync("tumbler.gui");
  }

let back = document.getElementById("ok");
back.onclick = function(e) {
  document.replaceSync("index.gui");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#ok` element is inside `tumbler.gui`, so it won't exist when your `document.getElementById` calls occur (because `index.gui` is loaded at that time).

It is necessary to load the `tumbler.gui` file **before** looking for `#ok` and setting its `onclick` handler.

When `tumbler.gui` is loaded, [all of the references to elements in `index.gui` are invalidated and the handlers are destroyed](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/device-api/document/#replacesync-):

> NOTE: All document and element handlers and listeners will be cleared after calling replaceSync.

so the `index.gui` setup (looking for elements, setting handlers) will need to be performed **again** after returning from `tumbler.gui`.

Here's how I would go about this:

```js
import document from 'document';

// index.gui elements
let myRect;

// set up index.gui after load
function setUpIndexScreen() {
  myRect = document.getElementById('gen_button');
  myRect.onclick = function() {
    document.replaceSync('tumbler.gui');
    setUpTumblerScreen();
  };
}

// tumbler.gui elements
let tumbler, back;

// set up tumbler.gui after load
function setUpTumblerScreen() {
  tumbler = document.getElementById('tumbler');
  back = document.getElementById('ok');
  back.onclick = function() {
    document.replaceSync('index.gui');
    setUpIndexScreen();
  };
}

setUpIndexScreen();
```